# Cannot rotate element using JS

Tags: javascript, css, rotation

I want to rotate my element using javascript. My method for rotation:

```js
function AnimateSidebar(sidebar) {
        sidebar.style.width = "20%";

        let arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
        arrow.style.transform = "rotate(60deg);";
        arrow.style = "tranform(rotate(60deg));";

        arrow.style.mozTransform = "rotate(60deg);";
        arrow.style.msTransform = "rotate(60deg);";
        arrow.style.oTransform = "rotate(60deg);";
        arrow.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(60deg);";
        
        arrow.style = "margin-left:85%;margin-right:0;";
    }
```

I tried to rotate it in several ways, as you can see above, but nothing works. The last line of code to change the margin of the arrow element works fine.

My css for the arrow element: (the initial rotation in css file works ok)

```css
#arrow{
    transform:rotate(20deg);
    transition:0.8s;
}
```

My browser is Microsoft Edge.

EDIT: Solved. I had to put the margin property above the tranform property.

Answer (score 1):

The bug appears to be that you have a semicolon inside the string value of your transforms.

`Element.style.transform` expects the exact CSS, so writing -

`arrow.style.transform = "rotate(60deg);";`

is roughly interpreted as -

```
#arrow {
   transform: rotate(60deg);;
}
```

Notice the double semicolon, which is invalid CSS.

```js
let arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
arrow.style.transform = "rotate(60deg)";
```

```css
#arrow {
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow">→</div>
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. As I said, the last line of JS works fine, despite containing the semicolon in the string.

Comment: Ah yes that last line was overriding all of the statements above. The semicolon works in that last line as you are setting the complete style and not just a single value.

Answer (score 1):

Leave out the `arrow.style = "tranform(rotate(60deg));";`

Try to first change the margin and then transform the arrow afterwards:

```
arrow.style = "margin-left:85%;margin-right:0;";
arrow.style.transform = "rotate(60deg)";  //without the semicolon!
```

Or directly set the margin-left using the style margin property:

```
arrow.style.marginLeft = "85%";
```